# How do i find out what type of object this is? (React/Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get rid of this any definition:

```
const [nextLocation, setNextLocation] = useState(null) as any[];
```

Below is a link to an image of the object. This is using react router 6. I've scoured available documentation, cannot find an object type that works.

[object example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G297C.png)

Comment: Please [do not show pictures of code](/help/how-to-ask). Just copy the code into your post as real text, with code formatting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Location` is a type from the `history` package which is used by react-router.

I'm not sure if you actually want to keep the Location or next Location in state, but I don't know your thoughts on this.

The correct way would be:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import type { Location } from 'history';

export default () => {
  const location = useLocation(); // current location
  const [nextLocation, setNextLocation] = useState<Location>(location);

  // or with initial null as value
  const [nextLocation, setNextLocation] = useState<Location | null>(null);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried this, but does not work. In another place in the code, I'm using the nextLocation like this: navigate(nextLocation?.location, nextLocation.location); If Itype it to Location, i get the error "property location does not exist on type "Location".

Comment: Yes, because `location` is not a property of the [`Location`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/dev/packages/history/index.ts#L100) interface. I'm not sure if it is possible to navigate using a Location object and I really think you shouldn't be using this. Why not storing a `nextPath` property instead and use `navigate(nextPath)`?